# My SHP file does not appear on my base map

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, polygon-creation, vector-layer

I am using QGIS 2.18.3 with a base map named Natural_Earth_quick_start_for_QGIS

I use Australian Albers EPSG: 3577

When creating a bunch of polygons on my base map, my QGIS suddenly stopped working. So I had to re-start QGIS and added vector layers that I was working on again. After retarting and changing the default coordinate to Australian Albers EPSG: 3577, almost all of the layers that I have just created previously do not show up, except for the layer named Cambodia Chamic1.

[image: photo here]

**What seems to be the issue here? how to make them show up**.

This is a list of the files associated with my created polygons [image]

**=========================================================================**
**=========================================================================**

@ Joseph

I did check the Coordinate reference system of my layers at *Properties > General > Coordinate reference system*. All of my layers have CRS as WGS 84, EPSG: 4326 which is not the same as my chosen projection *Australian Albers EPSG: 3577*.

[image]

But the layer named *Cambodia Chamic1* still shows up on my base map, whereas other layers having the same setup do not show up.

When I change the Coordinate reference system of all of my layers from *WGS 84, EPSG: 4326* to *Australian Albers EPSG: 3577*, the layers that have not shown up still do not show up

[image]

and the only layer that's showing up (Cambodia Chamic1) suddenly disappears.

[image]

I don't know what's going on right now?

Comment: Here is inside one of .prj files: http://postimg.org/image/mzbqidshl

Comment: Yes. I mis-posted my question on an unrelated site. So now I re-post it here so that my question may look right place, right time. I've deleted my post in stackoverflow.com

Comment: Are you sure all your layers are set to the same CRS as the projection? You can check this by right-clicking your layer and going to `Properties > General > Coordinate reference system`.

Comment: I had pretty much the same problem after QGIS crushing. I've just created the new project, added layers and everything worked fine.
I also got some advanced styles, so I saved them and reload in the new project.

Comment: @Joseph (take a look at the newly added description in my post):  I did check the Coordinate reference system of my layers at Properties > General > Coordinate reference system. All of my layers have CRS as WGS 84, EPSG: 4326 which is not the same as my set projection Australian Albers EPSG: 3577. But the layer named Cambodia Chamic1 still shows up on my base map, whereas other layers having the same setup do not show up. When I change the Coordinate reference system of all of my layers from WGS 84, EPSG: 4326 to Australian Albers EPSG: 3577, the layers that have not shown up still do not....

Comment: @Laurentz - I noticed you have `On-the-fly transformation` (OTF) enabled. I stopped using this a while ago as I normally had problems with it, instead I made sure all layers I use were **reprojected** to the relevant CRS (i.e. right-clicking each layer, selecting the `Save As...` option and saving the layer as new shapefile with the new CRS). Hopefully others can advise on how to get it to work with `OTF` enabled :)

Comment: OK, thanks for your help so far, Joseph. I'm still waiting for other members' advices.

Comment: What are the extents of the missing layers? You may have to start a new instance of QGIS (without the basemap) and add them in. That should confirm whether they're in decimal degrees, EPSG3577 or something else.

Comment: After choosing a new project (Ctrl+N) and adding my layers without the base map, all of the layers do not show up either with EPSG: 4326 or EPSG3577      https://postimg.org/image/v3xmscj21/

Answer (score 1):

(I am not allowed to comment yet due to the reputation limit, please consider this like one...)

I might be wrong here but the file size of all your data is 1Kb, according to the picture you provided. It is possible (especially when in edit mode while the crash occured), that your data got corrupted (I had similar experiences in the past).
This does absolutely not need to be the case or the reason for those layers not showing up, one can add a couple of polygons without increasing the file size and having CRS related issues is way more likely!
But, with the layers loaded, could you check the attribute tables, just to be sure there is data?
Or is that only a created list representation of the files? Then: nevermind...